# Submitting strongly typed repeating partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, partial-views

Im making a form in ASP.Net MVC 3 C#.

This particular page of the form contains the user's employment history.

The user can have more than one employment history. So the view model contains a list.

Now it would be easy to so this (and it works):

```
int i = 0;
foreach (FrgCandidatePortal_2.Models.tblCandidateEmploymentHistory item in Model.empHistList)
{
<div>
        <label>
            Employment History @Html.Encode(i + 1)</label></h4>
    <label>
        Company Name</label>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.empHistList[i].LJCOMP)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.empHistList[i].LJCOMP)
    </div>

...

  </div>
 i++;
}
```

BUT i want to be able to add an empty one using a button and ajax.
SO i figure "ill make it a partial view".
**QUESTION 1: is a partial view the correct way to handle a recurring form element that needs add remove and save functionality?**

Now I've made it a partial view and this is my view model for the page:

```
public class EmploymentHistoryViewModel : ViewModels
{
    private List<EmploymentHistory_Partial> _EmploymentHistory_Partial_List;
    public List<EmploymentHistory_Partial> EmploymentHistory_Partial_List
    {
        get
        {
            if (_EmploymentHistory_Partial_List.Count == 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (tblCandidateEmploymentHistory item in dataModel.candidateModel.tblEmpHistList)
                {
                    _EmploymentHistory_Partial_List.Add(new EmploymentHistory_Partial(i, item));
                    i++;
                }
                return _EmploymentHistory_Partial_List;
            }
            else
            {
                return _EmploymentHistory_Partial_List;
            }
        }
        set {
            //foreach emphist partial fill emp hist
            _EmploymentHistory_Partial_List.Clear();
            dataModel.candidateModel.tblEmpHistList = value.Select(c=>c.empHist).ToList();
        }
```

Basically my view model is a list of _EmploymentHistory_Partial's.
That displays data correctly when i use this code in my employment history view:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (FrgCandidatePortal_2.Models.EmploymentHistory_Partial item in Model.EmploymentHistory_Partial_List)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_EmploymentHistory_Partial",new FrgCandidatePortal_2.Models.EmploymentHistory_Partial(i,Model.EmploymentHistory_Partial_List[i].empHist));
}
```

BUT IT DOESNT SUBMIT
**QUESTION 2: Why don't the values submit to the model on post?**

(Im assuming its something to do with mvc naming conventions in the html document)

---

**UPDATE**

PROGRESS!

by editing the html of one of the fields (so that ID and NAME equaled EmploymentHistory_Partial_List[0].empHist.LJCOMP instead of empHist.LJCOMP) before i submitted when debugging. IT WORKED. It got to the set of EmploymentHistory_Partial_List in the view model.

So its naming. What seems to be happening is the partial view isn't inheriting the beginning of the naming from the rest of the form (and quite rightly). **Is there any way to make that happen?**

Comment: Forgive my possible ignorance but i don't think editor templates can render multiple "rows" representing a model. They just give you an editor for the model, where as i need to have zero or more of the model in one page. I would then have to use foreach like i did initially. but then that prevents me from easily accessing it through ajax to add another. I would have to reload the page and add an empty one to the end of the list. That would work, but it is clunky. I want to be able to JUST get the partial/whatever.

Comment: http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems i need to implement Html.BeginCollectionItem. Feel free to submit that as an answer and i will give you n accept and thumbs up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use EditorTemplates](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/), either through an `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper or just by calling `Html.EditorFor(Model.EmploymentHistory_Partial_List)`.